# Toggle between two div couples when you click on them

Tags: html, toggle

I've found some Javascript code on the web for toggling between two **images** when clicking on them as in this [example](http://justfortesting.yolasite.com/).

Now I wonder how to achieve the same result using divs with the pictures being inside the divs.

Both the small and the large image will each be the background image of a div which is inside another div that forms the border (I need to do this to be able to set the inner border radius of the image, which I can when I use an inner div and set its border radius). So I have:

```
<div class="bordersmallpicture"><div class="smallpicture"></div></div>
```

and

```
<div class="borderlargepicture"><div class="largepicture"></div></div>
```

How can I tell Javascript to toggle between those two div couples instead of images? Here is the Javascript code that I found for the images:

```
<script>
var imageURL = "small-picture.png";

if (document.images) {
var smallpicture = new Image();
 smallpicture.src = "small-picture.png";

var largepicture = new Image();
largepicture.src = "large-picture.png";
}

function changeImage() {
 if (document.images) {
   if (imageURL == "large-picture.png") {imageURL = "small-picture.png";}
   else {imageURL = "large-picture.png";}

   document.myimage.src = imageURL;
 }
}
</script>
```

And the HTML part:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeImage();"><img src="small-picture.png" name="myimage" title="Click to resize" alt="tree"></a>
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to edit this code to toggle between the div couples mentioned above? Or will a whole new code be necessary when dealing with divs?

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to toggle the classes. See a [running example](http://jsfiddle.net/gq59E/) using your images as CSS background in the classes:

```
<div id="border-div" class="bordersmallpicture">
  <div id="image-div" class="smallpicture"></div>
</div>
```

The the Javascript becomes:

```
<script>
function changeImage() {
  var currentClass = document.getElementById('border-div').className;
  if(currentClass == 'borderlargepicture') {
    document.getElementById('border-div').className = 'bordersmallpicture';
    document.getElementById('image-div').className = 'smallpicture';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('border-div').className = 'borderlargepicture';
    document.getElementById('image-div').className = 'largepicture';
  }
}
</script>
```

If you expect using javascript a lot, I recommend using jQuery which would make the code easier:

```
<script>
function changeImage() {
 $('#border-div').toggleClass('bordersmallpicture').toggleClass('borderlargepicture');
 $('#image-div').toggleClass('smallpicture').toggleClass('largepicture');
 }
</script>
```

[toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) turns ON/OFF a class (Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/EAPCA/1/))

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, it does work. Here is the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/gq59E/

Comment: if you have the image as a background, well then it will work :) first of all you should explain that, as the poster is using img tags, furthermore this is not a good solution if you use a lot of images. That would mean adding two css-classes (big and small) for each image. What if he has hundreds of images?

Comment: Hey JScoobyCed, thank you so much for this comprehensive reply. It worked out fine! You've made my day. Thank you for the hint on jQuery as well. You're right that the jQuery code looks much simpler, but I also appreciate the longer Javascript code because I can learn from it (still need to I guess). Giorgio, thank you for your comments, too. I just have that one image, so the solution is good for me, but I will consider your objections if I want the same thing for a page with more pictures.